# Explanation of "inclusion reversing".

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

So I am currently self-studying Galois theory with no one to ask questions to and
that is why I am here. Anyways,
I was reading about the fundamental theorem of Galois theory on this website here https://jhavaldar.github.io/notes/2017/10/19/galoistheory1.html and I am stuck on Proposition 4:

"The above association is inclusion reversing:

If $F_1 \subseteq F_2 \subseteq K$ then $Aut(K/F_2) \leq Aut(K/F_1)$

$\vdots$

"

The proposition continuous and states other things as well. The part that I do not understand is "inclusion reversing", what is that? And what does it mean for $Aut(K/F_2) \leq Aut(K/F_1)$? Is this stating that the cardinality of $Aut(K/F_2)$ is less than $Aut(K/F_1)$?

Comment: The "$\leq$" means "is a subgroup of" here. A map $f$ is "inclusion reversing" if $A \subseteq B \implies f(B) \subseteq f(A)$.

Comment: If $G$ and $H$ are groups, $G \leq H$ is the same as $G \subseteq H$.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Oh okay, thank you! But is there any reason behind the choice of symbols here? Why not use $\subseteq$ instead of $\leq$? I am thinking that there might be something "deep" that I am missing here...

Comment: @azif00 No, that is not true. Only if the inclusion is a homomorphism, which happens if and only if the group structure on $G$ is the one inherited by $H$.
For a counterexample, consider the inclusion of the multiplicative group of units $\mathbb Z^\times \{-1,1\}$ in $\mathbb Z$ together with addition. They have different neutral elements and incompatible group multiplication.

Comment: @LukasJuhrich Oh right. I forgot that detail. Then only $G \leq H$ *implies* $G \subseteq H$.

Comment: @gabbe1237 Be a *subgroup* is a stronger condition that be a *subset*.

Comment: In this case it actually is the same, since all the automorphism groups fixing a certain subfield by definition get their group structure from the „big group“ $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ they are contained in.

Comment: Oh okay! Did not notice the "group" part in your answers for some reason... Thank you all for answering my question! I will now be ready to move forward in life. Without you guys, I would be stuck at a dead-end! In return, I would like to buy everyone here a beer someday. Until then, my brothers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a partially ordered set (poset) is a tuple $(X, \leq)$ of a set together with a reflexive, transitive and antisymmetric relation on $X\times X$.

We can now define the following:

**DEFINITION** If $(X, \leq)$ and $(Y, \preceq)$ are posets, then an *anti-monotone map* (or *antitone map*) is a map $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $x\leq x'$ implies $f(x')\preceq f(x)$.

In the case where the partial order on both sets stems from an inclusion, we call an antitone map *inclusion-reversing*.
In particular, the statement now becomes:

**PROPOSITION**
Let $K/F$ be a normal and separable[1] field extension.
The map $f\colon F_1 \mapsto \operatorname{Aut}(K|F_1)$ is a well-defined antitone map between the posets

1. $(\{\text{Intermediate fields of}\ K/F\}, \subseteq)$
2. $(\{\text{Subgroups of}\ \operatorname{Aut}(K)\ \text{fixing}\ F\}, \leq)$.

Here, $\leq$ is the relation “is a subgroup of”. However, since the subgroups we are concerned with inherit their group structure from the big group $\operatorname{Aut}(F)$ they are all contained in, they are a subgroup if and only if they are included, i.e. $\leq$ is the same as $\subseteq$.

[1] I'm Not sure how much that can be weakened here, the precise demands are however irrelevant for the point I'm making.

---

Note that we can formulate antitone maps a bit differently using the notion of a *reverse order*:

**Observation** If $(X, \leq)$ is a partial order, then the relation $$
\geq\colon x\geq x' \Leftrightarrow x'\leq x
$$ turns $(X, \geq)$ into a partial order as well. We will call that relation the *reverse order* or *opposite order* of $(X, \leq)$.

**Proposition** A map $f\colon (X, \leq) \to (Y, \preceq)$ is antitone if and only if $f\colon (X, \leq) \to (Y, \succeq)$ is [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_order_theory).